# Python 3.9, print(file1.read) with no output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ve been learning about files in python 3.9.6 when this happen:

- I open a file using the open command
- Write to a file
- printed the text with file.read()
- the file.read() type is str
- print (file.read()) will return nothing .

I am using python 3.9.6 , pycharm community and python IDLE gave the same result,  and the problem is , i assumed that if we passed th file.read() which is a string , the print command will be able to actually print it .

```
>>>file1 = open('t.txt', 'a')
>>>file1.write('hahah')
>>>file1.close()
>>>file1 = open('t.txt', 'r')
>>>file1.read()
'hahah'
>>>print(file1.read())

>>>type(file1.read())
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: After the first `read()`, you have read the entire contents of the file. Subsequent `read`s have nothing left to return. Assign the result of `read()` to a variable if you want to refer to it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

the problem is that you are read the all the file in the first `file.read()`, which means that you get to the end of the file, so every time (until you will close the file) that you will run `file.read()` you will get empty string (`''`).